# Blank page when trying to connect to a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to host a php website and MySQL database using 000webhost.com, but when I try to connect to the database it just shows a blank white screen with no errors.

here's my connecting file.

```
 $db = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $error_message = mysqli_connect_error();
    include('database_error.php');
 }
 exit();
```

here's the page that's just blank.

```
<?php
   require_once('database.php');
   $query = "select * from projects";
   $projects = mysqli_query($db,$query);
   include("navbar.php");
?>

<div>
  <h1>projects page</h1>
  <div>
  <?php foreach($projects as $project):?>
    <div class="projectItem">
      <h2><?php echo $project["name"];?></h2>
      <h3><?php echo $project["description"];?></h3>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: What does `database_error.php` look like? Wouldn't that be pertinent...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exit();` function in your database.php include is causing all script execution to stop. So everything below that code (everything below `require_once('database.php');` ) is not executing.

Remove that line and then re-test.